# portaudio on osx 10.11

Tags: matlab, osx-elcapitan, portaudio

I would like to install portaudio on OSX El Capitan 10.11.

I have downloaded the latest snapshot and tried to install, and I got something about frameworks not being available. I hacked the configure script to help xcodebuild find the framework for 10.11 and now I get: 1

```
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core_utilities.c:152:10: error: 'kAudioUnitErr_IllegalInstrument' is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
case kAudioUnitErr_IllegalInstrument:
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Headers/AUComponent.h:1633:2: note: 
  'kAudioUnitErr_IllegalInstrument' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    kAudioUnitErr_IllegalInstrument                 = -10873,
    ^
src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core_utilities.c:155:10: error: 'kAudioUnitErr_InstrumentTypeNotFound' is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
case kAudioUnitErr_InstrumentTypeNotFound:
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Headers/AUComponent.h:1634:2: note: 
  'kAudioUnitErr_InstrumentTypeNotFound' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    kAudioUnitErr_InstrumentTypeNotFound    = -10872,
    ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [src/hostapi/coreaudio/pa_mac_core_utilities.lo] Error 1
```

I now understand that is because carbon is no longer available in 10.11.

Is there any way around this, or any way to install the previous frameworks? Or should I be using something else. I want portaudio to work so that I can install playrec and get duplex audio on matlab on a mac.

Comment: MATLAb ships the portaudio library as part of its install. I am not sure why you need to install PortAudio separately.

Comment: Yes you are right. I ended up solving my problem with dsp.AudioPlayer and dsp.AudioRecorder from the signal processing toolbox. Thanks for your help.